# Почему выводит None значение?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Imagine you're writing a cash register application. To make
> interaction easier on the user, it doesn't have separate areas for
> passwords, PIN numbers, or cash totals -instead, it looks at what the
> cashier enters and infers whether it's their PIN number, their
> password, or the cash total for a transaction. The register makes this
> decision with the following rules:
>
> - If the cashier entered only digits, then it's a PIN number.
> - If the cashier entered a decimal number, then it's the transaction amount.
> - If the cashier entered anything else, then it's theirpassword. Write a function named interpretCashier. interpretCashier should take one
>   parameter as input, which will always be a string initially.
> - If the string entered represents a PIN number, return "PIN".
> - If the string entered represents a transaction amount,  return "Transaction".
> - If the string entered represents a password, return  "Password".

В общем вот такая задача есть!
Ее легко можно решить используя функции `isdigit` или `replace`.

```
    def interpretCashier(as_string):
        if as_string.isdigit() == True:
            return "PIN"
        elif as_string.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit() == True:
            return "Transaction"
        else:
            return "Password"
```

Однако нужно помощь в решении без этих функций. И вот тут я застрял:

```
    def interpretCashier(as_string):
        try:
            if int(as_string) == True:
                return "PIN"
            elif  float(as_string) == True:
                return "Transaction"
        except ValueError:
            return "Password"

    print(interpretCashier("24.59"))
    print(interpretCashier("123456"))
    print(interpretCashier("my$up3rs3cur3p4$$w0rd"))
```

Почему выводит результат None?
И почему `int(as_string) == True` эта строка не читается?

Comment: что не так с исходной def interpretCashier(as_string)? возвращает же Transaction
PIN
Password

Comment: это функция которая изначально принимает только строки. Далее мы сравнием что вводится. Если класс int, то это PIN, если float - то Transaction, все остальное Password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно реализовать через "каскадный" try-except, и вообще без if

```
def interpretCashier(as_string):
    try:
        int(as_string)
        return "PIN"
    except ValueError:
        try:
            float(as_string)
            return "Transaction"
        except ValueError:
            return "Password"
 

print(interpretCashier("24.59"))
print(interpretCashier("123456"))
print(interpretCashier("my$up3rs3cur3p4$$w0rd"))
```

Answer (score 2):

int и float не проверяют принадлежность к типу, а пытаются привести к этому типу.

Поэтому сравнения типа `int(as_string) == True` будут делать совсем не то, что вы хотите.

Например, если `as_string` - строка `"1234"`, то `int(as_string)` будет целым числом `1234`. А оно, очевидно, не равно `True`.

Поэтому это условие оказывается ложное, точно так же как и условие с `float`. Поэтому ни один из ретурнов не выполняется и выводится `None`.

На экзепшнах логику можно построить как-то так:

```
def interpretCashier(as_string):
    
    try:
        int(as_string)
        return "PIN"
    except ValueError:
        pass
    
    try:
        float(as_string)
        return "Transaction"
    except ValueError:
        return "Password"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def interpretCashier(as_string):
    if as_string.isdigit():
        return "PIN"
    try:
        float(as_string)
        return "Transaction"
    except ValueError:
        return 'Password'
```

Answer (score -1):

потому что True это 1, а False это 0

```
>>> print(1.2 == True)
False
>>> print(1234 == True)
False
```

У вас нет блока else в условии, а функция по умолчанию возвращает None

```
>>> def foo(): pass
... 
>>> print(foo())
None
```

Очевидно, что если перестать сравнивать с True, то все заработает

```
def interpretCashier(as_string):
    try:
        if int(as_string):
            return "PIN"
        elif  float(as_string):
            return "Transaction"
    except ValueError:
        return "Password"

print(interpretCashier("24.59"))
print(interpretCashier("123456"))
print(interpretCashier("my$up3rs3cur3p4$$w0rd"))
```

Comment: В таком виде функция никогда не выведет значение Transaction

Comment: Точно! Спасибо!

Comment: @insolor я отвечал на вопрос

Comment: Вопрос «почему возвращает None?» а вот на какой вопрос вы отвечаете я не знаю

Comment: видимо в этом и разница) я без переводчика читаю)